# INotifyPropertyChanged only gets value but does not set value

Tags: c#, wpf

i checked many threads regarding this problem here but found no solution for my specific
case.
Have a WPF c# Net 6 based project. In this a modal Dialog window for get/set paramaters.
The get from dialog works, the set not.
xaml code:

```
<Window x:Class="MyApp.ParamDialog"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp"
    Title="Instrument Properties Dialog" Height="450" Width="400">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <DockPanel Grid.Row="0" LastChildFill="true">
        <Label  Content="int property" Margin="0,5,0,0" Width="130"/>
        <TextBox  x:Name="myIntProperty" TextWrapping="NoWrap" TextAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5" Text="{Binding myIntProperty,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay, IsAsync=true}" />
    </DockPanel>

    <!-- Buttons -->
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,10,0,0">
        <Button Content="OK" Width="80" Height="25" Margin="5" Click="OKButton_Click"/>
        <Button Content="Cancel" Width="80" Height="25" Margin="5" Click="CancelButton_Click"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

This is c# code:

```
using System.Windows;

namespace MyApp {
using System.ComponentModel;

#region class DataContextParamDlg
public class DataContextParamDlg : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    private int _myIntProperty = 100;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
        if (PropertyChanged != null) {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
    public int myIntProperty {
        get { return _myIntProperty; }
        set {
            _myIntProperty = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("myIntProperty");
        }
    }
}
#endregion

public partial class ParamDialog : Window {

    private DataContextParamDlg _DataContext;

    public ParamDialog() {
        InitializeComponent();

        _DataContext = new DataContextParamDlg();
        DataContext = _DataContext;

        // works not -> not shown in text box ###problem###
        _DataContext.myIntProperty = 2;
    }

    public DataContextParamDlg DataContext {
        get; private set;
    }

    private void OKButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        DialogResult = true;

        // this is fine. output carries value typed in TextBox
        int output = _DataContext.myIntProperty;
    }

    private void CancelButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        DialogResult = false;
    }
}
```

}

Finally raising the dialog:

```
ParamDialog dlg = new ParamDialog();
bool? result = dlg.ShowDialog();
```

How to solve ###problem### ?
Many thanks

Also this solution without extr DataContext is not solving the problem:

```
This code also just get and does not set.

using System.Windows;

namespace MyApp {
using System.ComponentModel;


public partial class ParamDialog : Window {


    public ParamDialog() {
        InitializeComponent();


        // works not -> not shown in text box
        myIntProperty.Text = "2";

    }

  

    private void OKButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        DialogResult = true;

        // this is fine. output has value of TextBox
        int output = System.Convert.ToInt32(myIntProperty.Text);
    }

    private void CancelButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        DialogResult = false;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You must not create a new DataContext property in your ParamDialog class that hides the existing DataContext property. Remove the entire declaration of the `public DataContextParamDlg DataContext` property.

Comment: I don't know why it does not work, but a workaround would be to set the property before assigning the DataContext: `_DataContext = new DataContextParamDlg { myIntProperty = 2 };   DataContext = _DataContext;`

Comment: @Olivier problem is the additional DataContext property that hides the existing one.

Comment: Thank you for answers, unfortunately, when removing DataContextInstrumentDlg and also member of this class in Dlg, have same problem, so not set, just get. myIntProperty = "2"; Is not working as well.

Comment: Sorry, myIntProperty.Text  = "2"; is not solving this.

Comment: What is DataContextInstrumentDlg? Please edit your question and show us your actual code.

Comment: In the same application, the MainWindow works with a DataContext and there is a TextBox that works fine for get and set. Couldn't figure out difference to the Dialog Window. However, the DataContext itself seems not to be the problem.

Comment: I thought DataContextInstrumentDlg is required to exchange data between model and view. I followed your proposal and removed DataContextInstrumentDlg.

Comment: There is no DataContextInstrumentDlg in your question. And once, edit your question instead of showing additional code in an answer. Show us exactly the code that you currently have. In the question, not in a comment or an answer! Edit here: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77648111/edit

Comment: Sorry, should be DataContextParamDlg. However,using DataContext or not, i does not set. Just added the code without DataContext and it is still not working. What's the secret here.

Comment: You are getting it all wrong. The fact that your additional DataContext was wrong does not mean you could not use data binding. Removing exactly only the declaration of the additional DataContext property should have made the Text Binding work. Besides that, `myIntProperty.Text = "2";` should of course also work, provided that there still is a TextBox with that name in the XAML of ParamDialog. It is unclear what exactly you are doing.

Comment: It should be clear now. Please just take the original xaml and the upated cs code at the bottom of my post. The TextBox name is myIntProperty, it is in the xaml and referenced as property in ParamDlg. Still only get is working, not set. myIntProperty.Text = "2"; should be fine to set the value?

Answer (score 0):

Removing

```
Text="{Binding  myIntProperty,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,       Mode=TwoWay}"
```

from xaml solves this problem.
Here is the working xaml and code to remove all confusion i may raised by this:
xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="MyApp.ParamDialog"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp"
    Title="Instrument Properties Dialog" Height="450" Width="400">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <DockPanel Grid.Row="0" LastChildFill="true">
        <Label  Content="int property" Margin="0,5,0,0" Width="130"/>
        <TextBox  x:Name="myIntProperty" TextWrapping="NoWrap" TextAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5" />
    </DockPanel>

    <!-- Buttons -->
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,10,0,0">
        <Button Content="OK" Width="80" Height="25" Margin="5" Click="OKButton_Click"/>
        <Button Content="Cancel" Width="80" Height="25" Margin="5" Click="CancelButton_Click"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

and code behind:

```
using System.Windows;

namespace MyApp {
    using System.ComponentModel;


    public partial class ParamDialog : Window {


        public ParamDialog() {
            InitializeComponent();


            // works now. Removing xaml parameter - > Text="{Binding myIntProperty,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" 
            // solved it.
            myIntProperty.Text = "2";
        }

        public DataContextParamDlg DataContext {
            get; private set;
        }

        private void OKButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            DialogResult = true;

            int output = System.Convert.ToInt32(myIntProperty.Text);
        }

        private void CancelButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            DialogResult = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not actually solve the problem: now you can't use data binding... See my answer to understand the true cause of the issue and why removing the binding from the TextBox will make your constructor assignment work.

Comment: Additionally, naming the property "DataContext" should give you a compiler warning as this will hide the original property inherited from `FrameworkElement.DataContext`. You should use a better and more specific name. If you want a clean control design, then treat the DataContext anonymously. A control should not know its data context.

Comment: You should delete this post.

Answer (score 0):

You have a simple timing issue.

The bindings are resolved *after* the constructor has returned.
This means, the initial value retrieved from the data binding ("100") will always overwrite the value set from the constructor ("2").
When you think about it, then this behavior makes absolute sense. There is no instance until the constructor has returned. Bindings on a type or its child elements can't be applied before the type itself is constructed and ready to be referenced by other types (including the binding engine component of the WPF framework).

To solve your issue, you can handle the `FrameworkElement.Loaded` event.
You should also use `int.TryParse` to convert a numeric `string` if you want to support empty strings and `null` (`Convert.ToInt32` will throw in such cases):

```cs
public partial class ParamDialog : Window
{
  private DataContextParamDlg _DataContext;

  public ParamDialog()
  {
    InitializeComponent();

    _DataContext = new DataContextParamDlg();
    DataContext = _DataContext;

    this.Loaded += OnLoaded;
  }

  private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    myIntProperty.Text = "2";
  }

  private void OKButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    DialogResult = true;
    
    // But why this extra conversion when you have stored a reference to the DataContext
    // and could simply get the value from there? 
    // For example: 
    //int output = this._DataContext.myIntProperty;
    if (int.TryParse(myIntProperty.Text, out int output))
    {

    }
  }

  private void CancelButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    DialogResult = false;
  }
}
```